# Parent child relation without cascade

Tags: java, jpa, orm

Are there case with is usefull to not use cascade in a parent - child relation?
Actually I use alway cascade and i would like to know if that could be interesting to avoid to use them.

```
@Entity
public class Lodger{
    @OneToMany
    private List<Bail> bailList;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Bail {
     @OneToMany
    private List<Rent> rents;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lodger_id")
    private Lodger lodger;

    @OneToOne
    private Room room;
}

@Entity
private class Rent{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bail_id")
    private Bail bail;

    @OneToMany
    private List<RoomPayment> roomPayment;
}

@Entity
private class RoomPayment{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "rent_id")
    private Rent rent;
}
```

So all relation seem to be composition. If i create a new RoomPayment, is it better to do:

```
roomPayment.setRent(rent);
roomPaymentDao.save(roomPayment);


rent.getRoomPayment().add(roomPayment);
rentDao.save(rent);
```

Comment: I can't see any cascades here? Do you want to know where to put cascades? In that case you should read my answer - the section about composition. I can't tell you which of your objects has _no independent existence_, because this depends on your domain. For example in one domain an engine always needs a car, in another it can exist on it's own.

Comment: So all relation seem to be composition, See my Edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up *compositions* and *parent - child relationships*.

**Composition**

From the [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition):

> It is ... called composite, if the objects it refers to are really its parts, i.e. have no independent existence

Composite relationships are always modeled with a `CascadeType.ALL` or `[CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE]` (the later for huge objects that you would like to update only if necessary). If you don't use a cascade here, you don't have a composition.

**Parent - child relationships**

There are different relationships that could be called *parent - child relation*. I guess you are talking about something like a directory association:

```
@Entity
public Directory {
  @ManyToOne
  private Directory parent;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
  private Collection<Directory> children;
}
```

In that case you will often need to manage the association manually, because you don't want to update the whole tree if you change an attribute of the root directory.

You could add `CascadeType.REMOVE` to the `children` association - but it is better to delete subdirectories explicitly to prevent harmful mistakes (like the explicit `-r` for `rm`).

Comment: ok, i edited  if i would like to save a new bail (without a rent)? how to save a rent? how to save a roomPayment?